# Problem excluding pages with siteMesh Struts2 Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, sitemesh

I'm using Struts2.2.1.1 with sitemesh 2.4.1 in Apache-Tomcat 6.0.29.
It works fine, but i can't exclude a file from siteMesh.

I Have My decorators in WebContent/jsp/decorators but i want to exclude the file WebContent/jsp/forms/Authentication.jsp. I tried using this decorators.xml with default dir = "/jsp/decorators":

```
<excludes>
    <pattern>../forms/Authentication.jsp</pattern>
</excludes>
<decorator name="main" page="layout.jsp">
    <pattern>/*</pattern>
</decorator>
```

I also tried to change pattern tag to use /jsp/forms/Authentication.jsp and didn't work either. Could anyone give me some pointers in the right direction? thanks a lot.

Juan David

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what you have, you need to configure the `excludes` in your `sitemesh.xml` file, like this:-

**decorator.xml**

```
<decorators>
   <excludes>
      <pattern>../forms/Authentication.jsp</pattern>
   </excludes>
   <decorator name="main" page="layout.jsp">
      <pattern>/*</pattern>
   </decorator>
</decorators>
```

**sitemesh.xml**

```
<sitemesh>
    <property name="decorators-file" value="/WEB-INF/decorators.xml" />
    <excludes file="${decorators-file}" />

    <page-parsers>
        <parser content-type="text/html" class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.HTMLPageParser" />
        <parser content-type="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.HTMLPageParser" />
    </page-parsers>

    <decorator-mappers>
        <mapper class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.mapper.ConfigDecoratorMapper">
            <param name="config" value="${decorators-file}" />
        </mapper>
    </decorator-mappers>
</sitemesh>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question, however i already have created in WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml a file containing exactly what you posted. And it doesn´t work either. Could it be something else? thanks

Comment: Your `login-file` property shouldn't be pointing to your jsp file. It should point to your `decorator.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you  limc. I tried leving the sitemesh.xml file just like you told me. And in that case i don't get the SAXException, but it still decorating my login page. But there us one thing that i don't understand... when i downloaded the blank sitemesh app from their website i noticed that they had a file called sitemesh-decorator.tld and sitemesh-page.tld but i didn't include them in my project or my web.xml file because they say that those file have to be included only if the container doesn't fully support JSP 1.2, are those needed? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It's really up to you. If you reference the TLDs in your decorators.xml and sitemesh.xml files, your IDE might be able to perform some validation checks against the TLDs, but I personally never used those. :)

Comment: Thank you limc. I just found out what the problem was... i had to remove the default dir from the decorators tag, and put every filepath absolute,starting from the /jsp folder. Thanks for your help :)